# QuickTime and a decompressor are needed to see this picture

Tags: libreoffice, quicktime, decompression

I have a LibreOffice Impress file, which I downloaded from the internet. Most probably it was made with something equivalent on a Mac, since all the pictures are replaced with this message: 
"QuickTime and a decompressor are needed to see this picture". 
Google only gave me results for Mac and Windows, but nothing useful for Linux. Then I've installed GStreamer and quicktime-utils, in the hope that I could use them to finally see the pictures. Now I am out of ideas and I hope someone of you had this kind of issue and know how to solve it. Thank you very much in advance!